# Python 2.7 skipping for loops in a function

Tags: python, function, skip

This is a simple program to encrypt and decrypt some text.
But it seems it doesn't work as expected..
I've also been told to use 2.7 no matter what
Your help is Appreciated, Thanks.

The Code in Python 2.7.16:

```
letterspace = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 
'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
input1e = ""
keyse = ""
input1d = ""
keysd = ""

def inpute():
    global input1e
    global keyse
    input1e = raw_input("Enter the message to be encrypted : ")
    input1e = input1e.upper()
    #keyinput = "Input the key (Key should be of length " + str(len(input1e)) + ") : "
    keyse = raw_input("Enter the key : ")
    if len(keyse) == len(input1e):
        return
    else:
        print("Please input the values correctly!")
        inpute()

def inputd():
    global input1d
    global keysd
    input1d = raw_input("Enter the message to be decrypted : ")
    input1d = input1d.upper()
    #keyinput = "Input the key (Key should be of length " + str(len(input1d)) + ") : "
    keysd = raw_input("Enter the key : ")
    if len(keysd) == len(input1d):
        return
    else:
        print("Please input the values correctly!")
        inputd()

def conv(x):
    for k, v in enumerate(letterspace):
        if v == x:
            print(k)
            return k
        else:
            continue

def reconv(y):
    for k, v in enumerate(letterspace):
        if k == y:
            print(v)
            return str(v)
        else:
            continue

def encryptor(inpe, keye):
    encm = []
    enck = []
    encf = []
    ence = ""
    for i in inpe:
        encm.append(conv(i))

    for k in keye:
        enck.append(conv(k))

    for x in range(0,len(encm)):
        z = int(encm[x]) + int(enck[x])
        if z > 26:
            z -= 26
        encf.append(z)

    for w in encf:
        ence += reconv(w)

    print ence

def decryptor(inpd, keyd):
    decm = []
    deck = []
    decf = []
    dece = ""
    for i in inpd:
        decm.append(conv(i))

    for k in keyd:
        deck.append(conv(k))

    for x in range(0,len(decm)):
        z = decm[x] - deck[x]
        if z < 0:
            z += 26
        decf.append(z)

    for w in decf:
        dece += reconv(w)

    print dece

def menu():
    print("---------------------ONE-TIME-PAD-PROGRAM---------------------")
    sel = raw_input("Type E for Encryption or D for Decryption :")
    if len(sel) > 1:
        sel = sel[0]
    if sel == "E" or sel == "e":
        inpute()
        encryptor(input1e, keyse)

    elif sel == "D" or sel == "d":
        inputd()
        decryptor(input1d, keyse)

    else:
        print("Please enter correct value!")
        menu()

menu()
```

Output: A is 0, B is 1 and so on..

```
---------------------ONE-TIME-PAD-PROGRAM---------------------
Type E for Encryption or D for Decryption :e
Enter the message to be encrypted : welcome
Enter the key : pragyan
22
4
11
2
14
12
4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mnsan/Downloads/Pri/OTP.py", line 110, in <module>
    menu()
  File "C:/Users/mnsan/Downloads/Pri/OTP.py", line 100, in menu
    encryptor(input1e, keyse)
  File "C:/Users/mnsan/Downloads/Pri/OTP.py", line 61, in encryptor
    z = int(encm[x]) + int(enck[x])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

It skips the second for loop in line 57.
My idea : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run the script. Is this the outcome you are waiting for?

```
Type E for Encryption or D for Decryption :e
Enter the message to be encrypted : WELCOME
Enter the key : PRAGYAN
22
4
11
2
14
12
4
15
17
0
6
24
0
13
L
V
L
I
M
M
R
LVLIMMR
```

The problem is that your letterspace is in upper and the input you give is in lowerletter. So when it tries to use the function `conv`,it doesn't find anything to match to, so it returns empty and `int(enck[x])` is full of Nones.

You don't have problem with the first word because its just numbers.

You can see here the nones:
[image]

So, one thing you can do, is correctly define your letterspace, with both uppers and lowers.

Comment: alright, but in line 11 and 24, ive converted it into uppercase P:S : i forgot to convert the key to uppercase.. my bad :(

Comment: Yes BUT, you have only converted the `input1d` and `input1e` but not `keyse` and `keysd`. You also have to convert the key "pragyan", not only the input "welcome"

So it should be like this: 

`keyse = raw_input("Enter the key : ")
 keyse = keyse.upper()`

Edit: YAY! You found it :)